# Does my trigger updates all the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a simple trigger which sets a column value with the id column value.
This is my trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SubSectionsPrioritytrigger
ON SubSections
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE dbo.SubSections
SET Priority = Id
```

After writing this trigger that, does this updates all the records after each insert. Or the only created new row.

Could some one provide any info on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `Id`? Does it column of `dbo.SubSections`?

Comment: Currently that updates every row in the `dbo.SubSections` table. However I'm not quite sure on what you are meaning to do even if it only affects one row. Where does `Id` come from? If `Id` is an `IDENTITY` column or something, why not just set it as a computed column or create a view that exposes it as `Priority` as well, instead of adding a trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Update just the inserted row, you can do this:

```
UPDATE dbo.SubSections  
SET  SubSections.Priority = SubSections.Id 
FROM INSERTED
WHERE INSERTED.Id = dbo.SubSections.Id
```

Answer (score 4):

It does exactly what you wrote

```
UPDATE dbo.SubSections
SET Priority = Id
```

Any row will be updated.

You can change this to

```
UPDATE dbo.SubSections  
SET  SubSections.Priority = Inserted.Id 
FROM INSERTED
WHERE INSERTED.id = SubSections.id
```

this will affect only the inserted rows.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is updating all the records. Could you suggest me a change which will avoid updating all the records except inserted record.

Answer (score 2):

to update just the last inserted row to what ever value you want you need to specify that row id which makes that row unique, from other rows.
and in your trigger you have not specified a where clause which causes all rows in the table to be updated.
whenever a any operation/event occurs on the table which has trigger associated with it mean a new record is inserted/updated or deleted an magic table is created in memory of SQL Server and we can access that magic table with the keyword "Inserted" in case of insert or Update and "Deleted" in case of delete.
so your query should be like this.

UPDATE dbo.SubSections
SET  SubSections.Priority = SubSections.Id 
FROM INSERTED
WHERE INSERTED.Id = dbo.SubSections.Id